# Connector drawing - please help find C abbreviation/symbol meaning

Tags: technical-drawing

Please help me to identify what C5 stands for in this picture. Full drawing is available [here](https://www.qualtekusa.com/images/AC_Receptacles/pdfs/703w0004.pdf).

[image: Drawing]

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_drawing_abbreviations_and_symbols#C) Wikipedia article gives a hint it might be *centre-to-centre distance of two features*, but I cannot corelate.

Comment: That's a 5mm champher!

Comment: Defined in a similar way to the 4mm radius labeled R4.0

Comment: @JonathanRSwift Thanks! Just to confirm - top line length then equals to `28 - 5 - 5 = 18`?

Comment: Yep, and the angle will be 45degrees.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please add this as an answer - I will accept right away!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "C5" annotation in this example refers to a "5mm Champher". It's important to note, however, that this is non-standard notation. I have included an example below with the standard annotation for the champher on the LHS, and another alternative on the RHS.
[image: 5mm champhers]